# Storing user click information on MongoDB using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, statistics

I have a general question.

My MERN application contains certain user related links that are shown to the general public through the user's profile.

My goal is to track the number of clicks on each link, the time stamps of when those links were clicked,and what country/city those clicks came from.

This information is used to give the statistics of the above mentioned clicks to the user of my application.

Currently, I am using an array of objects in My MongoDB Schema in which I append an object containing the click information as follows:

```
const ClickDetails = new mongoose.Schema({
    country: { type: String, default: "" },
    city: { type: String, default: "" },
    date: { type: Date, default: ""},
    ip_address: { type: String, default: "" },
    device: { type: String, default: "" }
})
```

Here is a sample social media link schema where I want store my click information of the user's social media links using the above schema:

```
social_link_list: [{
        link: { type: String, default: "" },
        isActive: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        click_details: [ClickDetails] // As a user clicks on the link in profile, the click data is pushed to this array
    }]
```

As I will filter dates according to the user's requirement for analysis, is there a better way to store my data (or a better logic to track link clicks in general)?

Comment: It looks like a one-to-many relationship between the link and its details. The way you are planning to store looks alright. You may want to create some samples of data and write couple of important queries which you are intending to write, to understand the data structure works for your requirement. Creating some sample data and writing queries can validate your data design.